# How to boot from a Samsung 970 Evo Plus

Tags: ssd, nvme

I am having a trouble booting this drive. I have spent about 4 full days doing it on my own with all the help of known internet wisdom but I end up all the time failing.

How far I can go:
Basically I installed my NVMe disc, plugged in the Windows 10 boot stick in(GPT), BIOS set to UEFI.

Then I booted from the stick:

- Cleaned disc.
- Started installing.
- Completed first installation.
- Rebooted...

---

Couldn't do anything to make it boot after that reboot.
When I go to BIOS, it's visible, but not as one of the boot options.
I tried it on my laptop GP72MVR 7RFX Leopard Pro and on my desktop with the following specifications:

- i7 6700k
- Z170x-Gaming
- 16GB Ram
- GeForce 980 TI

Both with the same result.
What I did during the process is:

- Cleaned the disc with `discpart`, made sure that it's GPT and not MBR, but I did try that possibility too.
- Tried to clone it, but the size of the sector that NVMe got is a bollocks.
- Tried to install it with and without any other discs attached. BIOS is up-to-date in both cases.
- Tried every option in the BIOS to make it happen with CSM and without it.

I'm on the edge right now. Maybe I got the wrong part or something, but I'm not good enough to define that. And on the other hand, if I try to use it as storage it works completely fine. Write and read speeds are also fine. I did a bunch of stuff I didn't mention here, because I lost track half way to now. But I am still willing to do it properly - whatever it takes.

So, if anyone has some thoughts and is kind enough to share, I am here.

**PS:**
If I missed to give some important info, let me know. Never post about problems like that and don't know everything what you need to make it as easy as possible to you heroes.

Comment: Dont throw yourselfs at once... jesus seriously no one is able to help with booting ? shame on this forum